# Struggling with sharing protocol

Tags: linux, debian, windows, sshfs, shared-folders

I'll try to be as clear as possible, I was struggling for months trying to choose a sharing protocol of all the content of my server.

The scenario, one debian server with lot of GB of data, mostly all windows clients (some android), mostly lan shared but online too.

I was trying with sshfs until now, the windows client doesn't work as good as it should. I need something to could be mounted as a drive letter in Microsoft operating system.

I want to get rid to sshfs since it doesn't fit my requirements, but i don't want to go on insecure FTP (for the online part).

Comment: https://www.samba.org/

Comment: Samba, per SR suggestion.

Comment: And to explain the rationale behind Samba: Mostly windows clients means you want a protocol that's natively supported by Windows, and that's SMB in LAN. So Samba is really the only sensible choice.